# proces sliders tags in my specific php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello i'm near at the end of my form and have a little problem with collection values in php from my sliders. Slider  code structure:

```
<section1>
    <label class="label">Simple <p style="float:right">Complex</p></center></label> 
    <div id="slider1" name="slider1"></div>
</section1>

<section1>
    <label class="label">Playful <p style="float:right">Serious</p></center></label>    
    <div id="slider2" name="slider2"></div>
</section1>
```

Javascript

```
$(function()
{
    // Regular slider
    $('#slider1').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,             
        values: [50],
        slide: function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#slider1-value').text(ui.value);
        }
    });

    $('#slider2').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,             
        values: [50],
        slide: function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#slider1-value').text(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

I don't get any values from `slider1` , with this code structure , what should i do i'm not very familiar with php , any javascript or jquery ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You don't get the `slider1` value in your POST request because there is no `form field slider1`.
What you need to do is add an `hidden form element` and populate it when the slider is moved.
Like so:

HTML:

```
<section1>
    <label class="label">Simple <p style="float:right">Complex</p></center></label> 
    <div id="slider1" name="slider1"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="slider1-value" name="slider1-value" />
</section1>

<section1>
    <label class="label">Playful <p style="float:right">Serious</p></center></label>    
    <div id="slider2" name="slider2"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="slider2-value" name="slider2-value" />
</section1>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
     // Regular slider
     $('#slider1').slider({
         min: 0,
         max: 100,           
         values: [50],
         slide: function(event, ui)
         {
             $('#slider1-value').val(ui.value);
         }
     });

     $('#slider2').slider({
         min: 0,
         max: 100,           
         values: [50],
         slide: function(event, ui)
         {
             $('#slider2-value').val(ui.value);
         }
     });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'My Form';
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

        $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
            'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . "\n" .
            'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
            'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n" .
            'Country: ' . $_POST['country']. "\n" .
            'Web Site : ' . $_POST['url']. "\n" .
            'Simple vs Complex : ' . $_POST['slider1-value']. "\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    if($_POST['copy'] == 'on') {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: No it just don't get in :S its blank again besides thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

[The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts](http://api.jquery.com/text/). After

```
<div id="slider1" name="slider1"></div>
```

add

```
<input type='hidden' name='slider1val' id='slider1val' value='0' /> <!-- change value to initial -->
```

then change

```
$('#slider1-value').text(ui.value);
```

to

```
$('#slider1val').val(ui.value);
```

In your PHP `$_POST['slider1val']` will get the value.

Comment: yet i'm getting the nitial value i set as value when processing not the actual value, im looking if i have made a mistake anywhere besides thank you for your help

Comment: maybe it has to do with the values: [50], in javascript code ?